# return label text when clicked

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to print the label text (the element of `FunctionResults` when it is clicked).

```
import Tkinter
import os
import Func

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()
        self.Result =[]
        #self.minsize(8000,300)
        self.geometry("800x300")

    def initialize(self):
         self.grid()

         self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
         self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
         self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
         self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)
         self.entryVariable.set(u"")

        self.labelVars = []
        for j in range (1,30):
            labelVar = Tkinter.StringVar()
            labelVar.set('')
            self.labelVars.append(labelVar)
            label = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=labelVar,
                              anchor="w",fg="black",bg="white")

            label.bind("<1>", lambda event, text="some text": \
                          self.click_link(event, text))

            label.grid(column=0,row=j,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')




        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,False)
        self.update()
        self.geometry(self.geometry())       
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def OnPressEnter(self,event):
        #FunctionResults is a list returned by Func.Func1
        self.FunctionResults = Func.Func1(self.entryVariable.get())
        self.FunctionResults = list(reversed(self.Result))
        for i in range (0,len( self.Result)):
            print "result",i,":", self.FunctionResults[i]
            self.labelVars[i].set(self.FunctionResults[i])
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def click_link(self, event, text):
        print "you clicked '%s'" % text



        #l["text"]
        #os.system("open "+textvariable+".txt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = simpleapp_tk(None)
     app.title('my application')
     app.mainloop()
```

Instead, I get `you clicked some text`.

How do I write the function `click_link(self, event, text):` to get the name associated with the label that's clicked?

I have seen some answers on a similar topic using `command`, but I would prefer not to use a button.

Comment: What does `Func.Func1()` do?

Comment: `Func.Func1()` returns a list `Results`. THOSE results are the ones that are printed to the labels. Hence, when I click the label, I want to return the `Result[i]` that corresponds to that label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the text from the widget that was clicked like this:

```
def click_link(self, event, text):
    print "you clicked '%s'" % event.widget["text"]
```

**EDIT** full code working for me on Ubuntu 14.04 and OS X 10.10

```
import Tkinter
import os

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()
        self.Result =[]
        #self.minsize(8000,300)
        self.geometry("800x300")

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)
        self.entryVariable.set(u"")

        self.labelVars = []
        for j in range (1,30):
            labelVar = Tkinter.StringVar()
            labelVar.set('')
            self.labelVars.append(labelVar)
            label = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=labelVar,
                              anchor="w",fg="black",bg="white")

            label.bind("<1>", lambda event, text="some text": \
                          self.click_link(event, text))

            label.grid(column=0,row=j,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,False)
        self.update()
        self.geometry(self.geometry())
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def OnPressEnter(self,event):
        #Result is a list
        self.Result = self.entryVariable.get()
        self.Result = list(reversed(self.Result))
        for i in range (0,len( self.Result)):
            print "result",i,":", self.Result[i]
            self.labelVars[i].set(self.Result[i])
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def click_link(self, event, text):
        print "you clicked '%s'" % event.widget["text"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = simpleapp_tk(None)
     app.title('my application')
     app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I get `Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "gui.py", line 35, in <lambda>
    self.click_link(event, text))
  File "gui.py", line 60, in click_link
    print "you clicked '%s'" % event.widget["text"]
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: @user99889 Interesting, I updated my answer with my test code that worked for me on linux+mac.

Comment: I see how this works with `self.Result = self.entryVariable.get()`, but I want it to print an element from the list got from my outside `Func.func1()`

Comment: @user9989 well the issue seems to be that you're trying to use something that is not a string as text (within `Result`). Seems like it should be straightforward to convert the value you want to use as a `str`. Hard to help beyond that without seeing the code for `Func` though.

Comment: It needed to be `% event.widget["text"][0]` :)